# How to make a hibernate query case sensitive?

Tags: string, hibernate, where-clause, case-sensitive

I have the following hibernate query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findByName", query = "SELECT e FROM t=Table e WHERE  e.name =:name")
```

And here is how I set the parameter

```
uniqueResult(namedQuery("findByName").setString("name",name));
```

Will this differentiate a "name" from "NAME"? I read that `setParameter()` is case sensitive, should I change `setString()` to `setParameter()`?

Comment: To my recollection by default queries are case sensitive. Have you actually tried running this first?

Comment: yeah setString does not recognize the difference,

Comment: Are you referring to `:name` i.e. the parameter name? not the actual value of the parameter?

Comment: teh actual value

Comment: Hibernate does not do anything with the actual value. `setString` uses `setParameter` underneath and executes the exact same code. This could be an issue as per the answer below regarding your database.

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on your database and the collations used. Some databases have collations that are `CI` case-insensitive and `CS` case-sensitive. For instance on MySQL `latin1_general_ci` and `latin1_general_cs`.

Hibernate is not aware of this fact and simply executes a standard `WHERE` clause yielding the behaviour the database is configured to.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: came across this option, in other SO posts.. but I still dont know how to work this out in a JPA named query